# Sharing photo on FB's latest apk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, sharing, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to share a photo on Facebook.

I have login working, and the share dialog will pop up with `sharelinkcontent` but not with photo.

It will not pop up at all, but it is running and hitting this code.

Here is my code:

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class)) {
//            ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
//                    .build();
//            shareDialog.show(linkContent);


        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.common_plus_signin_btn_text_light);

        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(icon)
                .build();

        SharePhotoContent photoContent = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .build();

        shareDialog.show(photoContent);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook SDK's versions 4.0+ have changed the way you can share content on facebook.
For photos, you need to use PhotoShareContent.
For links, the ShareLinkContent.

A requirement of the SharePhotoContent is that you must have installed the native faceboook app in order to share photos.

From [Facebook Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

> Photos
>
> People can share photos from your app to Facebook with the Share
>   Dialog or with a custom interface.
>
> - The photos must be less than 12MB in size
> - **People need the native Facebook for Android app installed, version 7.0 or higher**

On the other hand, to share a link is not necessary the facebook app, that's why your code works when you use ShareLinkContent

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems odd to me that they would require you to have the app installed, but now I know.